# Women having long hair

Tags: women, hair

Is there a reason for why women have long hair?

Does the Torah provide us with a reason?

Comment: Why do you think women having long hair has anything to do with Torah and not just style?

Comment: Certainly, within Tanac"H, the term "long" would really require comparison, and probably a larger one than what you would currently use. Two men in Tana"ch described as having long hair are Absalom and Samson. With that as a basis, how would you define "long hair" for women? Esp. that I don't think that tanac"h describes any woman's hair at all.

Comment: Perhaps that the style for women until recently has been to have long hair, and having short hair would violate the mitzvah of gender separation? It is true, though, that some Chassidic Orthodox women shave their heads underneath the sheitel they wear.

Comment: Are you asking about hoe the hair grown naturally, or how it is often styled?

Comment: @DanF It actually does, within Shir HaShirim and actually Bamidbar 5:18. Both imply women have long hair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's one of the ten curses Eve got cursed from God listed in Eiruvin (100,b) [she should grow hair as Lilith](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=3&daf=100b&format=text).

Comment: Did Lilith have long hair? How do you know that?

Comment: @DoubleAA From [here](http://www.rossettiarchive.org/docs/n5054.r47.rad.html#2-1867.s205)

Comment: A 19th century poem?? Can you provide a traditional Jewish source maybe?

Comment: @Double why isn't the implication of the Gemara enough to answer your question?

Comment: @user6591 What implication? What does the Gemara mean and how do you know?

Comment: @Double Could Migadeles Sa'ar mean anything besides growing hair? It's not like Assisa which might mean grow or cut.

Comment: @user6591 Maybe Lilith didn't have hair on her face and that's why women don't but men do. They grow hair like Lilith did.

Comment: @Double wasn't expecting that. OK. I still don't think that would be called migadeles. I would assume that would be referred to as einah migadeles etc. But stay tuned to my upcoming comment.

Comment: @IrRelevant using a poem which was influenced by the societal practice around it as a proof seems wrong. I could show a 19th century painting of Moshe as fair skinned but I wouldn't use that as a proof that he was Norse. He was as the painter imagined him based on his own surroundings. Also, you ask why women have long hair -- isn't the answer "because they don't cut it"? A woman who cuts her hair has short hair. A man who doesn't has long hair.

Comment: @Ir a have already +1'd this. However, be aware there may be some type of machlokes medrashim here. See Ruth Rabba 6:1 where Ruchos (Sheidim) are described as not having hair. Radal there says to see his explanation on Pirkei DiRabi Eliezer chapter 14 where he addresses this discrepancy, but I don't see what he is referring to now.

Comment: @Danno the thing is, the entire sugya is based around common practice. Women cover their hair like a mourner, Rashi says because they are embarrassed to walk out uncovered. They pierce their ears like a slave etc... This is all assessments of (what was once) normative behavior. The whole insight was why exactly do they have this nature.

Comment: Sorry I didn't take Double AA's comment seriously. The Tiferes Yisrual [Bikurim 4, 6](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=37940&st=&pgnum=368) seems to understand it this way.

Comment: The [chidushei aggadot](https://www.sefaria.org/Chidushei_Agadot_on_Eruvin.100b.6) says women cover their hair because that is the type of hair lilit had.